# How to connect to Softether VPN server

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have a Softether VPN server on my VPS. It is OpenVPN compatible. I can connect using OpenVPN app on iOS. I also connected on Windows without any problem but I could not make it on Linux.

I installed `network-manager-openvpn-client` on my client computer.

When I try to create a OpenVPN connection it asks me for certificate files but there is not any. I only have a OpenVPN configuration file (`.ovpn`).

How can I make this connection? I'd be grateful if you could point me to the right direction for the solution.

My purpose is to use only this connection, prevent any other net access and make this connection automatically on login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably that the .ovpn file has inlined key/certificates. 
You need to separate them into
other files and change the .ovpn file to refer to those files.
If you open the .ovpn file you'll see the inlined key/certs and then can refer to openvpn manual.
I had the same problem on ubuntu and breaking it up fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I created a "server.cer" file using the text block under the title of "certificate file of the destination VPN server" in the ovpn file. Then I selected Password option, I entered my password and selected that certificate file at the same time. It worked.

Comment: I can connect directly without separating certificates file from downloaded `.ovpn` file. Probably a system bug on handling `.ovpn` file?